# How to mark as unread just one message and not the entire conversation in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Sometimes I want to mark just one message as unread and not tue entire conversation, so when I open the conversation only the unread message is readily visible (like when new messages are added to a read conversation - when you open it, only new messages are readily visible)

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't as of now. Sorry!

There is one option though .. 
Go in Google Labs (once you are logged in on Gmail) .. then enable **Mark Unread From Here** and try!!

Description of what it does ..
*

> Adds a new option to each individual
>   message's drop-down menu that will set
>   that message and all following
>   messages as unread, so when you come
>   back to the conversation later you can
>   pick up reading where you left off.
>   Click the button with the triangle
>   icon in the corner of the specific
>   message you want to start reading from
>   later, then select "Mark unread from
>   here"

*

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does exactly what I wanted, gave it a try and worked, tahk you!