# Archive one mail from conversation view

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations, gmail-archive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I archive only certain messages within a conversation?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12064/can-i-archive-only-certain-messages-within-a-conversation)

Is there any way of moving only one mail from conversation to *Archive*?

For example if you accidentally move *Sent* mail to *Inbox* it would be only possible to move it back by turning off Conversation View in Setting:

> Conversation View:
>
> (sets whether emails of the same topic are grouped
>   together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to duplicate your issue:

- "Move to Inbox" adds the "Inbox" label to a conversation.
- Archive strips the "Inbox" label from the conversation.
- Sending a message adds the "Sent Mail" label to a conversation.
- "Move to" command when looking at the "Inbox" label adds label X and "archives" the message, stripping the "Inbox" label

The archive button doesn't touch the "Sent Mail" label.